# Some php files doing nothing on my xampp server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

As part of a larger project I wanted to include a header.php and menu.php into a page.

I'm at my wits end to figure out why it isn't working.

All files are in C:\xampp\htdocs

The include file, test.inc.php, contains:

```
<?php echo 'does this work?'; ?>
```

The file I am including it in, testheader.php contains:

```
<?php include 'test.inc.php'; ?>
```

Nothing happens, it's just a white page. No error or anything.
I have searched and I have confirmed and ruled out the common solutions I found:

-Directory/locations issues (I've used all possible variations including the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])

-All file extensions are .php not .html or anything else

-Using full `<?php ?>` tags

-I've tried using `require` or `require_once` but it isn't even registering an error. It simply thinks nothing is there.

At first I thought it was just an include issue, but more disturbing is I cannot get it to parse ANYthing inside a `<?php ?>` tag now. It's not just the includes. 
If I make a .php file and just type "test" in it, it will print out "test" but if I try to do `<?php echo 'test'; ?>` it just becomes a blank page.

But only for these files. I have another set of pages that use php tags extensively with a mysql db and they work just fine.
Complex php files running scripts with mysql that work perfectly right alongside this file with a simple echo that does nothing? Why? 
The ones that work are a week or more old, anything new doesn't work. 
Nothing has changed, not my browser(use Firefox but its the same on IE/Chrome), not my editor (gedit), not my xampp version (1.8.3).

My last resort is a fresh install of xampp but I'd like to know WHY this happened so I can avoid or fix it without having to reinstall if it happens again.

**EDIT:**
The default Line Ending in gedit may have changed to Windows instead of Unix/Linux which I read somewhere is what it should be. When I resaved the files to Unix/Linux Line Ending they worked.

I have everything working now. This explains why some files were working fine and others were not. The older files had been saved with the correct Unix/Linux setting and therefore worked.

Sorry this is my first stackoverflow question. Should I "Answer" it myself or how do I close it?

## Solved!

Comment: What happens if you combine your tests and include some HTML and PHP. Does the HTML display or is the page blank?

Comment: Have you checked your apache logs yet?

Comment: @Shoeless I only get the html

Comment: @Zarathuztra I'm not much of an apache expert so yes, but I have no idea what I'm looking at. One thing that stands out is when I start Apache I get this:
`[Sat Jun 28 11:12:15.998200 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4632:tid 260] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Jun 28 11:12:16.029200 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4632:tid 260] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.`
But there is nothing in the php error logs or access.log

Comment: Blank page normally means that PHP is not configured to display errors. You need to sort that out first and fix actual errors afterwards.

Comment: I get errors all the time in the past and I got them in the example below as well. There's an issue on one of my old pages with a null cell and an error I'm aware of and it also appears just like it did a week ago. Edit: nvm I guess that would be an sql error. But I do get an error when I change the single quotes on the echo command to ticks like you posted.

Comment: Try: `<?php include('test.inc.php'); ?>` in your testheader.php...

Comment: @BigChris parenthesis are unnecessary. I got it to work, it was all in how the files were saved and apache didn't like it I guess. Why only some files weren't working and others were.

Comment: Please scroll down the page and find the "Answer your own question" button. If you paste answers into the question itself it's confusing and there's no way to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run PHP program in XAMPP(Cross-Platform (X), Apache (A), MySQL (M), PHP (P) and Perl (P)), try to follow the below mentioned steps :

Follow these steps to test your XAMPP installation by launching the Apache web server and creating a simple PHP file.

Step 1: In the XAMPP control panel, click on ‘Start’ under ‘Actions’ for the Apache module. This instructs XAMPP to start the Apache webserver.

Step 2: Open your web browser and type in: http://localhost or 127.0.0.1

Step 3: Select your language from the splash screen.

Step 4: You should see the following screen. This means you’ve successfully installed XAMPP on your computer.

Step 5: We will now test whether XAMPP has installed PHP successfully. To do this, fire up Notepad and type the following into a new document:

```
<?php

   echo ‘Hello world’;

?>
```

Save this file as ‘test.php’ in c:\xampp\htdocs\ (or whichever directory you installed XAMPP in).

Step 6: Navigate your browser to localhost/test.php. You should see the “Hello World” message

Hope the above answer is sufficient for your question.

If you need further drop your comments.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, this is basically exactly what I said I'd already tested...but did it anyway.
But this time I do get an error message which is new:
` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'worldâ€™' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3`
(Step 1-5 worked fine until I loaded test.php)

Comment: @jbigs: you can use the code snippet in this answer to test your error reporting settings. You should be getting *PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'world’' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'* if everything's fine.

Comment: Yes and I do have a new corresponding error in php_error.log but I don't get anything in the pages I run in my main question that also has a simple echo command.